# Yii2 ActiveDataProvider find()->all()

Tags: yii2

Maybe i miss understand something about ActiveDataProvider, when i want to join table with `->joinWith('user_display')->all();`
I've got error: The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = FinanceSettingsCheckoutcounter::find()->joinWith('user_display')->all();


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

        return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ActivedataProvider needs a query. In your case you send the result of the query (`all()`)

```
$query = FinanceSettingsCheckoutcounter::find()->joinWith('user_display');
```

Comment: I can't disply data then, 'attribute'=>'user_display.user_id' in gridview did'nt show anything. Here is my user_display function:                                                     public function getUser_display()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User_display::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
            ->viaTable(FinanceSettingsCheckoutcounterUsers::tableName(), ['finance_settings_checkoutcounter_id' => 'id'])
            ->from(['user_display' => User_display::tableName()])  ;
    }